How the binary code space alignment influence the runtime efficiency?
I was optimizing some C language codes and realized a weird thing.
I noticed a piece of useless code (not being used by any parts) and deleted it. But the performance went down by around 4%, which is not influenced by CPU because I already tested it multiple times and during different times in several days.
Besides that, I also found out that when I compile this project using Makefile, which takes all .c files as inputs and generates an output binary, the performance is good. But when I divided the code into different modules and used CMake to compile it separately, and combined them together at the end, the run time performance was totally different from the Makefile version (worse than the Makefile version). By the way, the platform, the compile option (always including -O3), and the GCC version remain the same for sure.
I checked the binary code using reverse engineering tools and found that the compiled codes are almost the same, but the function sequence and virtual address space of course are different.
So I am confused about that. I guess this is caused by the code space arrangement, like the code space size, code address alignment, etc.
And fortunately, I found an answer: Why does GCC generate 15-20% faster code if I optimize for size instead of speed?. So the alignment truly influenced the performance.
But are there any methods or tools to find the best way to align the code? Because I tried using -falign-functions=32 -falign-loops=32 but it is not always working. Sometimes it makes the performance even worse. And so does the option -flto.
So, I am wondering if we can truly know in which situations we need to tell the compiler using alignment while we don't in others. Are there any tools that could be helpful to analyze this problem?

Sorry if stating the obvious, but did you also try using -O3? I'm asking since approximately 100% of performance-related questions on SO can be explained by the use of incorrect benchmarking methods.

Yes, I use -O3 to generate the binary. Sorry for the confusion about this, I edited the question and added it to the text. And the benchmarking method I am using is running the core function in the while loop multiple times in a fixed time, then calculate the operation per second (op/s).

It can vary with choice of compiler too. I find that for my heavy floating point maths code gcc -O3 and all the go faster options enabled that Intel ICX compiler will often beat it and MSVC 17.1 will sometimes beat it. I am admittedly still something of a novice on gcc. Intel's VTune tool can provide a lot of insight into where bottlenecks really are and their profile directed compilation can sometimes sort them out. Slow or fast usually comes down to code fitting nicely into a cache line and branch target alignment.

Changes to memory layout can cause some extra paging if related codes aren't on the same memory page, and can also cause related codes to be in different cache lines. Unfortunately this can be very difficult to predict and control. Usually the impact should be minor, 4% difference seems extreme.

That's why I was confused when I saw the huge difference (in some cases even larger than 4%). We can not predict the memory layout though, are there any coding styles or compiler-specific options/keywords that could be used to make it as good as possible?

The effect of loop alignement and size can be much bigger that 4% or even 15-20%. It can be twice slower in pathological cases (and sometimes even more). See for example Why is my loop much faster when it is contained in one cache line? (where it is twice slower due to cache lines).

There are other cases to consider like CPU bugs like the JCC erratum for example. The thing is this is not as simple as it seems since jump instruction needs not to cross a cache line, even when merged by the CPU. The µop cache also matters. Thus, setting -falign-functions=32 -falign-loops=32 is quite naive. AFAIK there is an option for the JCC erratum but it is not enough to cover all pathological cases. I think the question is too general and you should focus on a more specific example. Details matters a lot for performance, especially in such a case.

"Are there any tools that could be helpful to analyze this problem?" Note this part is off-topic on Stack-Overflow, but be aware that hardware performance counters can be used to track such issue (which are CPU-dependent since this is a CPU-dependent problem anyway).
